# First color movie to use flickering and slamming door trope?

Tags: first-appearance, trope

Horror movies often show flickering of lights and slamming doors to signify presence of supernatural, ghosts and etc.

Which was the first color movie to use this trope?

Comment: Like *forever*....going back to the earliest days of cinema.

Comment: It is used in *Nosferatu*, 1922.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horror_film#1889.E2.80.931900s

Comment: @Chenmunka - given the state of projector technology and the electrical grid in 1922, how would an audience know that the flickering was actually part of the movie?  :D

Comment: @PoloHoleSet: Good point. Edited my question.

Comment: They were flickering candles, shown being blown by draughts.